# How to design a 3-phase resistive load bank?

Tags: power, three-phase, load, resistive

We are trying to design a 3-phase resitive load bank to test some step up transformers. We are receiving 3-phase 208v and stepping up to 3-phase 600V with 3-step up transformers wired in delta. Its a floating system  Each step up transformer is capable of 800VA.

Q. How do you wire up the load with resistors, to test each transformer at full load? A picture or diagram would be helpful.

Comment: Is your resistor bank intended to be used for load imbalance simulation?

Comment: If possible, having some way to test with load imbalance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGcbgl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Delta transformer with delta load.*

> Each step up transformer is capable of 800 VA [at 600 V].

- From \$ P = \frac {V^2}{R} \$ we get \$ R = \frac {V^2}{P} = \frac {600^2}{800} = 450 \ \Omega \$.

> If possible, having some way to test with load imbalance would be helpful.

450 Ω is your minimum on any phase. You can use any load between 450 Ω to infinity (open-circuit) on each phase.

Comment: He's using 1 800VA transformer per phase and you changed a 267 into a 167.  At any rate, he's got 800VA per phase at 600V, so he wants to be able to test 600V@1.333A RMS per phase. 
That gives 450 ohms per phase and a power rating of ~1000-2000 W per phase.

Comment: Yup. Speed reading late at night is risky. Thank you. How did you calculate 1000 - 2000 W per phase?